# Andorid: layout data variable :XML file cannot ViewModel class

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, data-binding, viewmodel

Im new to the concept of conecting ViewModel directly to the XML file and I really don't know why Gradle cannot find ViewModel class.

Bellow I post my code and error log.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT : Main Activity is only Host for the fragment and this Fragment instantiate ViewModel

CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="tvm"
            type="com.uj.bachelor_jlk700.examsystem.screens.test.TestViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".screens.test.TestFragment">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_testFragment_name"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@{tvm.userName}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035" />
```

Error MSG

```
C:\Users\Jan\AndroidStudioProjects\ExamSystem\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\uj\bachelor_jlk700\examsystem\databinding\TestFragmentBinding.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
import com.uj.bachelor_jlk700.examsystem.screens.test.TestViewModel;
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class TestViewModel
```

[ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQAsf.png)

[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxnwe.png)

[Fragment - Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x91ja.png)

Comment: where did you instantiate your ViewMdel in MainActivity.. also you didn't define binding object in MainActivity

Comment: ViewModel is instantiate in Fragment

Comment: is the provided layout for fragment?

Comment: Yes, it is layout for fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You xml layout can't identify the **tvm** object that refers to the `TestViewModel` class, and you need to explicity define the instance of the `TestViewModel` class in your fragment.

To do that in your fragment within `onCreateView()` of your fragment class:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders...
binding.setTvm(viewModel)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer.